# Validate form with checkboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes in a form as follows:

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return window.Validate()" method="post" action="myprog.cgi">
    <div id="filters"> 
        <input name="One_f" type="checkbox"> No. 1<br> 
        <input name="Two_f" type="checkbox"> No. 2<br> 
        <input name="Three_f" type="checkbox"> No. 3<br>
    </div>
    <div id="Colors">
        <input name="Red" type="checkbox"> Red<br> 
        <input name="Blue" type="checkbox"> Blue<br> 
        <input name="Green" type="checkbox"> Green<br>
    </div>
    <div id="Button">
        <input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to write a function `Validate` in Javascript that would see whether any of the checkboxes in the div id 
`filters` is checked. If none of them is checked, it should show an alert box and prevent the cgi from 
getting executed. The checkboxes in the div `filters` all have their names ending in `_f`, if that helps.
How do I write such a function?

Comment: Is jQuery an option? Would make it much easier.

Comment: I have no idea about jQuery...I would much prefer it to be in pure Javascript, if that is possible.

Comment: Well, it would greatly reduce the code necessary and make it more readable...

Comment: I suppose you could give the code in jQuery, if you wish...maybe someone else would solve this using js. I'll give both a try, if I can understand your solution, that is!

Comment: Now you have both solutions to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) solution, I'll add a plain JS one in a few moments.

```
$('form[name="form1"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(!$('#filters input:checkbox:checked').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please select at least one filter.');
    }
});
```

This codes does **not** require the `onsubmit` inline event.

Since you are not familiar with jQuery I'll explain it more thoroughly:

- `$('form[name="form1"]')` creates a jQuery object containing all elements matching the selector. It would be faster if you gave your form `id="form1"` and used `$('#form1')`
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) binds an event handler. The first argument passed to the callback function is a wrapped event object which we'll need to prevent the form from being submitted if necessary.
- `$('#filters input:checkbox:checked')` selects all checked checkboxes that are children of `#filters`. `:checkbox` and `:checked` are pseudo-selectors which will only match checkboxes that are currently checked)
- `.length` is the number of elements in the jQuery object - if nothing is checked it's zero
- [`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) prevents the default action of the event from being executed, i.e. the form will not be submitted.

Usually you would wrap the whole code with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` to make it execute as soon as the DOM is ready - if you put the `<script>` tag containing the code after the `</form>` tag of your form, it's not necessary though.

---

If you really want a plain JS solution, try this:

```
function Validate() {
    var container = document.getElementById('filters');
    var checked = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var elem = container.childNodes[i];
        if(elem.tagName == 'INPUT' && elem.type == 'checkbox' && elem.checked) {
            checked++;
        }
    };
    if(checked) {
        return true;
    }
    alert('Please select at least one filter.');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving me both solutions...I'll try to figure out the jQuery one first.